# White space in MongoDB Compass Community

Tags: mongodb, whitespace, mongodb-compass

For some reason in MongoDB Compass Community my values are displayed as if there was a large amount of white space in them. But when I click on the value there is no white space to delete. Also, I can't move the cursor into this white space. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

See the white spaces behind every value here:
[image]

See here, when I click on the value the cursor is at the end of the text, but still you can see a weird white space display:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is that GUI for Mongo? MongoDB itself doesn't "display" anything.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. This is on MongoDB Compass Community